# How to use slurp/gorge/staticRead/staticExec in the directory of the callsite?

Tags: nim-lang

The compile time functions `slurp`/`gorge`/`staticRead`/`staticExec` seem to use the directory of the source file as working directory. In most cases that is the desired behavior, because the relation of the source code and compile time resources is fixed. But how can I use these functions in a library so that they refer to resources provided by users?

Example structure:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── client.nim
│   └── resource.data
└── library
    └── library.nim
```

I want to provide a `bundle` function in the library, which allows the client to call something like `bundle("resource.data")`. Internally the library may use e.g. `slurp(givenResourcePath)`. However this will fail, because slurp looks up `resource.data` relative to `library.nim`. Is there a way to use these functions and refer to files relative to the callsite?

Note: I tried to generate the AST performing the slurp with a template/macro, but even than the lookup is relative to `library.nim`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to rely on a helper template that uses `instantiationInfo` to obtain the source path of the caller of the macro.

You can create a module called bundles.nim:

```
import os

macro bundleImpl(userPath, resource: static string): untyped =
  let resourcePath = splitFile(userPath).dir / resource 
  echo "FULL RESOURCE PATH ", resourcePath
  echo "FILE CONTENTS:"
  echo staticRead(resourcePath)

template bundle*(resource: static string) =
  bundleImpl(instantiationInfo(-1, fullPaths = true).filename, resource)
```

Then, you can use it from any module in the expected way:

```
import
  bundles

bundle "test.txt"
```

The result on my system is something like:

```
FULL RESOURCE PATH /Users/zahary/nim/scratch/test.txt
FILE CONTENTS:
<test.txt contents>
```

Comment: This seems to solve the related problem "how to get the user path from a macro". However, `slurp` & co don't allow to pass in a working directory in addition to the resource path and I was assuming that absolute are not supported either because the [corresponding PR was rejected](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/2303). If absolute paths work now, that would solve the problem obviously.

Comment: Within a macro, you can read the contents of any file with `staticRead`. I've updated the example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with a macro using a small trick: Looking up the implementation of `slurp` shows that it uses the lineinfo of the `slurp` AST node to determine its working directory. By default, constructing an AST with a macro attaches a lineinfo which refers to `library.nim`, and thus, slurp uses the library path. To modify the behavior, we can read the lineinfo from the callsite and attach it to the slurp node:

```nim
macro bundle*(resource: string): untyped =
  # create slurp call node
  var slurpCall = newCall(ident "slurp", newStrLitNode resource.strVal)

  # forward callsite lineinfo to affect working directory behavior
  slurpCall.copyLineInfo(resource)

  # embed slurpCall somewhere in output AST
  # ...
```